# Does it matter which of the identical looking strains of the pcie cable to connect to a GPU?

Tags: gpu

I have one GPU plugged into pciex16 1 and want a second to to be plugged into pciex16 2.
The PSU has different connections named pcie1...pcie4.

I plugged the pcie cable into the pcie3 connection of the PSU and plugged the GPU into the pciex16 3 slot.

My GPU has a 6 and 8 pin connection.

The problem is, 
the pcie cable has two strains of identical looking twin cables. Both have a head split into a 2 and 6 pins.
Does it matter which of them I put into the 6 pin connection of the GPU and which to the 8 pinned one?

PS:
Did I miss anything else critical?

Answer (score 2):

The 2-pin and 6-pin connectors typically fit together to make the 8-pin connector. You'll need one of these combinations and the other 6-pin connector for your card.

Though you may check the installation instructions and your PS documentation to confirm this.

Comment: Does it matter which of the identical cables I have to choose for each of the connections on the GPU?

Comment: I meant which of the identical looking strains of one pcie cable.

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred Your power supply has four pcie cables for convenience. Pick your favorite. Not sure what you mean by "strains" though, [that's not a sensical word in this context](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strain).

Comment: Sorry , it's not my mother tongue I mixed it up with "stränge".

Comment: The part plugged into the PSU has only one end, on the side to the GPU there are two parts A and B, each of them ends into a split head of 6 and 2 pins. I referred to these A and B parts and if it matters which part to choose for each of the 2 connections  on the gpu

Comment: The PSU may have multiple 12v rails that are presented via the 4x PCIe Power connectors. In this case, it would be beneficial to split the GPUs between the multiple 12v rails - 1 GPU on each rail. Check the manual for more info... or share the PSU model.